# How can I change schemas using JDBC to connect to MySQL in Grails?

Tags: mysql, spring, grails, jdbc, groovy

I'm using a spring bean to interact with SQL in a Grails app. My `resources.groovy` file looks like this:

```
beans = {
    groovySql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref('dataSource')) {}
}
```

My `DataSource.groovy` file has a data source set up (and named `dataSource`).

The JDBC connection string that I *had* been using looked something like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://my.domain.com/Schema_Number_One
```

And when I had it like that, **everything worked fine.** However, I now need to use more than just the one schema on that server. So I changed my connection string to simply this:

```
jdbc:mysql://my.domain.com/
```

I figured this would be fine, and that I could just issue a query like `USE Schema_Number_Two` to switch. But something's gone awry.

When I try to run this code:

```
def query = "USE Schema_Number_Two"
groovySql.execute(query)
groovySql.commit()
```

I get the following error in the console:

**Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed.**

So... apparently it sees the `USE` statement as a write query? My next thought was to try to trick it into thinking it was a read-only statement by doing this:

```
def query = "USE Schema_Number_Two; SELECT 1"
groovySql.execute(query)
groovySql.commit()
```

And while that query does execute without error, it doesn't stick. The very next query returned some error message indicating no database had been specified.

I've also tried adding `@Transactional(readOnly=false)` just before the method I'm calling here in my controller, but that doesn't seem to have any impact. And I can confirm that I'm using the Grails Transactional annotation.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/domurtag/runtime-datasources

Comment: I think you want runtime-datasources. The `dataSource` block is used to create a `DataSource` Spring bean, which wraps a connection pool that pre-allocates some minimum number of connections to reduce the connection time for queries to a few milliseconds. But that's not consistent with changing the database for each connection. And I'm pretty sure `USE` is a MySQL client command, not SQL, so that's not an option regardless. If you're willing to incur the time it takes to get new connections every time (and you shouldn't be, it'll add up) then you could skip pooling and use `DriverManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could tell, there was no way to accomplish what I was trying to do here. What I ended up having to do was simply to define separate data sources.